# React Native Maps Only Loads For Two Specific Locations (Cities)

Tags: react-native, react-native-maps

For some reason the map will only render when our location is one of the two cities where our app has been developed. For all other cities we just see the loading screens, and our app eventually crashes.

**For the two cities the app was developed in:**

Pulls user Lat/Long > venuesLoaded > renderMap > IT WORKS!

**For any other location when opening the map view:**

Pulls user Lat/Long > STAYS ON THE LOADING SCREEN/SOMETIMES CRASHES.

I can post our code if needed, just thought if anybody's had a similar experience from a similar situation before I piece it all together.

**Back Story:** We've taken over dev from another group of developers in the first city, and our dev team is located in the second city. The fact that the map will only render in these 2 cities makes me thing there is a small snippet of code left in there from the previous dev team, but we can't find anything unusual?

*Is there a key or function that would limit react-native maps to only a few specific cities?*

Comment: Sounds like it's unable to download the tiles that it needs.  Does your device have full internet access available? No proxy / firewall ?  The cities it can see might just be cached somewhere.    (Otherwise I think you'll have to post some code).

Comment: We just solved it. It pulls in an array of events and if there haven't ever been any events in that area it was passing array: null. Thanks for your help though!

Comment: I am getting the same issue can you explain? how you solved it?